# UIImageView losing the set aspect ratio when programatically changed

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am updating the image on my screen when the user swipes. Because this image come from the web I implemented an extension to UIImageview.

However the aspect ratio I have set for the image in the storyboard gets lost when I load in a new image.

This is the extension I am using for UIImageView:

```
extension UIImageView {
    public func imageFromUrl(urlString: String) {
        if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
            request.setValue("<YOUR_HEADER_VALUE>", forHTTPHeaderField: "<YOUR_HEADER_KEY>")
            NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
                (data, response, error) in
                guard let data = data where error == nil else{
                    NSLog("Image download error: \(error)")
                    return
                }

                if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse{
                    if httpResponse.statusCode > 400 {
                        let errorMsg = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                        NSLog("Image download error, statusCode: \(httpResponse.statusCode), error: \(errorMsg!)")
                        return
                    }
                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    NSLog("Image download success")
                    self.image = UIImage(data: data)
                })
                }.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

I then programatically change the UIImageView with this code:

```
frontviewimage.imageFromUrl("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/66/Android_robot.png")
```

I then tried changing the the content mode to scale to fit (below), but it seems to have no affect.

```
frontviewimage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;
frontviewimage.imageFromUrl(frontImageViewArray[cardStackPosition])
```

EDIT: I also tried:

```
frontviewimage.imageFromUrl(frontImageViewArray[cardStackPosition])
frontviewimage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;
frontviewimage.clipsToBounds = true
```

Here is an example of what it should look like:

[image]

But what happens on some images is below, it doesn't modify the size at all and the picture ends up taking the whole screen covering all the buttons:

[image]

I want to have whatever comes into the imageview be aspect but not sure how to do that.

Comment: You want the image to be the aspect ratio set in the storyboard, even if it looks stretched?

Comment: I want to do aspect fit which I am pretty sure fits but keeps the aspect ratio. Right now one of the images that is coming through is bigger than the phone screen so it is covering the whole screen.

Comment: Make sure `clipsToBounds` is true

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for your response, unfortunately that didn't change anything.

Comment: Are you seeing the problem with the Android image? I can't reproduce your problem with that image.  ScaleAspectFit is doing what you'd expect.

Comment: No it was an image from a private repository,  I can't put the address of that on here though. It was a large image.

Comment: @vacawama I have edited it to show you an example of what is happening.

Comment: Are you using a standard UIImageView?  Have you modified any of the settings from the defaults?  What constraints do you have on the imageView?

Comment: Yes, I added an extension to the imageview so that it downloads the image. The code is in the question. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I mean, in the Storyboard.  How have you set up the ImageView?  Did you just drag out the UIImageView element?  Did you change any of the settings for it in Xcode?  What Auto layout constraints for the ImageView did you set?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean yes just standard imagview. Set to aspect fit and clip subviews.

Comment: What constraints have you put on the imageView

Comment: @Paulw11 only positional (ie x, y), I may be wrong here, I thought that it needed to be able to get larger on larger screens.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks very much I think that was the problem. I will have to look more into how to handle imageview on a larger screen.

Comment: Yes, you need to  prevent he image view from resizing beyond the edges by using leading/trailing constraints (or top/bottom constraints). There are any number of image sizes that will satisfy an aspect ratio constraint